# build.xml:1: Premature end of file

Tags: java, android, xml, netbeans, android-ide

I am new in Android development, and I wanna build some apps for myself. I have installed Android SDK last version, NetBeans IDE 7.4 and also the plugin for this. I wrote a simple code for Android to see if it works:

```
package com.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
     {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           TextView tv = new TextView(this);
           tv.setText("HelloWorld");
           setContentView(tv);
     }
}
```

When I try to build and run with an emulator, I get this error: [path] \AndroidApplication1\build.xml:1: Premature end of file.
When I go to the file (build.xml) I see that is empty. I should write to it? What should I do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This may be NetBean's problem. Have you tried clean and re-build the project? Restarting NetBeans?

Comment: @XiaoChuanYu , I tried both methods, with no effects.

Comment: I agree with @XiaoChuanYu in that this is likely a problem with your project or ide setup. Try making a new project, or running through the framework installation guidelines again.

Comment: It was a problem with the sdk. I now try to reinstall it. Thank you guys! :)

Comment: is the problem solved?